# Where Can One Buy a Griz (Brisker Rav) on the Rambam?

Tags: product-recommendation, rambam, brisk

Does anyone know if the Griz al Harambam is available anywhere nowadays?

Thank you so much for any and all help.

I have tried ordering from many online and in-person seforim stores but to no avail.

Comment: The Responsa Project of Bar Ilan University may have it available on CD

Comment: It would help if you would tell us what you've tried already. Otherwise you may get answers like "try a Jewish book store; I bought mine there in 1957".

Comment: Also check the Otzar site

Comment: @msh this book was never been authorized for sale in a Jewish bookstore. It used to be sold only at the author's home (later, his widow's).

Answer (score 1):

Brisk and by Rov Dovid. I heard rumors they don't sell it other places, but probably some people would resell it.

Answer (score 1):

I bought a copy on Rechov Meah Shearim in Jerusalem, as far as I recall I bought it from Sifrei Meah Shearim.

Comment: How long ago did you buy it?

Comment: January this year